# how to add controls dynamically into datagridview due to row data

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

When using DataGridView, I want to add an extra column called "controls" to the end of each row. And there should be two buttons in the column called "Discard" and "Detail".

like below:

```
 No   Name   State  Controls
---- ------ ------ ------------------
 1    AAA    True   [Discard][Detail]
 2    BBB    False  [Discarded][Detail]
 3    CCC    True   [Discard][Detail]
```

The key point here is that the "Discard" button Enabled property should be set to False and label changed to "Discarded" when the row "State" data is false.

I can only add the column by

```
datagridView1.addColumn("ColumnControls", "Contorls");
```

but I dont know how to add the buttons due to row data.

I am using VisualStudio 2005 and SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `DataGridViewButtonColumn` to the `DataGridView`.

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn discardColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
discardColumn.HeaderText="Controls";
discardColumn.Name="Discard";
datagridview1.Columns.Add(discardColumn);
```

In the `DataBindingComplete` event handler, add the below code

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in datagridview1.Rows)
{
 row.Cells["Discard"].Text = "Discard";
 if(row.Cells["State"].Value.ToString() == false)
 {
   row.Cells["Controls"].ReadOnly = true;
   row.Cells["Controls"].Text="Discarded"
 }
}
```

Follow the similar logic for "Detail" column.

Comment: is possible to add two buttons in one column?

Comment: @hammer - as such datagridview doesn't support it. But you can create custom columns and do that. Also you can create your own user control with [two buttons](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/19620568-4f38-4e86-986a-d935529160ee/datagridview-adding-two-buttons-in-one-column?forum=winformsdatacontrols) and use it.